How to save header's value into Spring Security context considering concurrency safety
I have to use a header value for some utils logic in my kotlin spring application. I found a way to get header value for each request, but I realize that this way is not so good because of concurrency.
It is how I get and save the header value:
class HeaderInterceptor : HandlerInterceptor {
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun preHandle(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse, handler: Any): Boolean {
        val anonymousUserId = request.getHeader("anonymous_user_id")
        headerHolder = HeaderHolder(anonymousUserId)
        return true
    }

    companion object {
        private var headerHolder: HeaderHolder = HeaderHolder()
        fun getHeaders(): HeaderHolder = headerHolder
    }
}

@Configuration
class HeaderInterceptorConfig : WebMvcConfigurer {
    override fun addInterceptors(registry: InterceptorRegistry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(anonymousUserIdInterceptor())
    }

    @Bean
    fun anonymousUserIdInterceptor(): HeaderInterceptor {
        return HeaderInterceptor()
    }
}

data class HeaderHolder(
    val anonymousUserId: String? = null
)

To get the header's value I can just call HeaderInterceptor.getHeaders(). But it is totally bad idea because of importance of concurrency safety.
It seems like the ideal solution would be to somehow put the header's value into the spring security context. Then I could access it simply by calling:
class SecurityUtils private constructor() {
    companion object {
        fun getAnonymousUserId(): String? = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()... // an example way to access a stored value
    }
}

Since i will need to use the header's  value from including in utility classes in static methods, I would like to be able to access it without bean injection.
Maybe someone has already encountered something similar and was able to solve this problem? I would be grateful for any tips

it would be good to know why do you need this? And for how long do you need this headerId? Cause you have access to the current request in all of your controller methods, etc so you could autowire this information or pass it wherever you want? Which would be the best way to deal with concurrency issues - namely avoid them

For authorized users, I get the userId from the jwt token, but for unauthorized users, the userId comes in the headers. I can't influence this logic in any way, that is, I need to be able to get this value from the headers in any case. userId is used in many places for different purposes, so passing it, although it can seem logical, is very inconvenient, since almost all methods will have another argument. It would be much more convenient to get the value, for example, from the SecurityContextHolder, as I do now to get the token value

there is no need to reinvent the wheel, just authenticate with whatever authentication filter / logic you have and set it into the SecurityContext once user is authenticated - e.g. SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userId, "", List.of())). Example is shown here. You don't need to worry about concurrency since SecurityContextHolder defaults to MODE_THREADLOCAL and getContext will return Context for the current thread

The solution to my problem turned out to be quite simple. To get the header's value it is enough to refer to RequestContextHolder. Since there is also asynchronously executed code, I added a check for RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() existence.
private fun getValueFromHeader(headerName: String): String? {
    return if (RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() == null) {
        return null
    } else if (RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes() is ServletRequestAttributes) {
        (RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes() as ServletRequestAttributes)
            .request.getHeader(headerName)
    } else null
}

This method can also be static.
